# Match Paint Over Wall Repair

Tags: repair, paint

I have an apartment with 5 rooms inside. I painted the whole studio five years ago. I didn't really use the room. I left the apartment closed. The paint on the wall now dried out, a little faded from the original color. Some parts are damaged but the whole studio still remains the same.

I've already fixed the damage and I'm finding it hard to match the paint to the existing color of the room. I don't want to repaint the whole studio. Do you know any way to do that?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome. I think that the answer on that question covers your question pretty well. If you disagree, feel free to mention why. Otherwise this question will be closed as a duplicate. Don't let that dissuade you from posting more questions in the future.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that existing question. I can't find it when I create this question. It didn't suggest to me. 

Anyway, That only covered one side of my problem. I managed to get the exact paint color from the manufacturer but when I tried to paint on the wall, the new one and the old one doesn't seem to match. Like I said before, It got a little faded over time. 

Should I Keep this topic until I get the answer or should I ask this on the created question?

Comment: The second suggestion in that answer addresses your issue. Paint an entire wall. The only alternative is to keep trying to adjust the paint color, which gets expensive quickly and still may not be successful. Painting isn't difficult and with a little practice you can knock out a room in a couple hours anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to have a paint store match if you bring them a chip of the existing color. I think it may need to be at least the the size of a quarter. I recommend calling first to verify.

Comment: However you do it, you should not have to repaint an entire room. If you can't feather the patched area, you might have to paint as much as one whole wall, at most.